# Why is my AccountHistory object missing?

Tags: object

My AccountHistory object cannot be found by Data Loader nor within Salesforce Record Type.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? There is a checkbox to show more objects, check that and have a look on all the option for objects. Also, what are trying to do - Import or export?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have field history enabled. Check the `Enable Account History` to enable if not already.

[image]